# Settings, Appearance settings,Software and updates,Display settings are not accessible and not opening in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, settings

Suddenly my Settings, Background displays, Appearance settings and Software and Updates are missing or unable to open.
I even tried
`sudo apt install gnome-control-center`
and got this error

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-control-center : Depends: gnome-control-center-data (< 1:3.35) but 1:3.36.4-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                        Depends: language-selector-gnome (>= 0.179~) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-online-accounts (>= 3.25.3) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: ubuntu-system-service but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Even tried `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
An got this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: language-selector-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: software-properties-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-desktop-minimal but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: update-manager but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-software-plugin-snap but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: nautilus-share but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ubuntu-software but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please suggest me what should I do further,
Thanks in advance.